# Bus Kraków-Zakopane with a baby

Tags: buses, poland

We're planning to take a bus from Kraków to Zakopane (Poland) in June, with our 7-month old kid.
I've never been to Poland, but last year traveled several times by bus from the Baikal lake to Irkutsk (Russia) and would never like to do that kind of trip with a baby (drivers consistently went too fast for my taste).

How is the ride, traffic, and general speed? Would we find a baby seat or would we need to bring our own?
I'm asking because we could alternatively take a (slightly slower) train.

Comment: The distance is twice higher, and a year ago there were notable jams due to heavy road reconstructions shortly after leaving Kraków. It is probably safer to have your own seat, just in case. Have you considered renting a car?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buses on this route are fine, some may be a little older but there's no reason to be concerned. The drivers are also fine and obey the rules of the road. There may indeed be some roadworks. With a baby, I would recommend the train. You will be more comfortable and have more space.

It's much safer to travel by train or bus than by car.

Comment: Information on booking trains within Poland is contained in https://www.seat61.com/Poland.htm#Buying%20train%20tickets%20within%20Poland which may help the OP.

Comment: "It's much safer to travel by train or bus than by car." - though note that danger is extremely small anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I've never been to Russia, but I find bus travel in Poland versus former Soviet states quite different. You should be fine, drivers are safe and buses are quite modern and comfortable, especially if you travel with big companies such as [FlixBus](https://www.flixbus.pl/) (formerly Polski Bus). You'll be unlikely to find baby seat, though*.

Please note that [train travel](http://rozklad-pkp.pl/en) is almost twice longer and more expensive at the same time. On the other hand, train travel time is predictable, whereas buses are subject to traffic, and Kraków-Zakopane road is often congested and there are currently roadworks ongoing.

Please also note that between

<sup>* - you'd best bring your own child seat with you. If you arrive in Poland by plane, check your airline regulations. Some airlines allow you to take child seat in addition to "standard" luggage. Last time we've flown, we'd been able to check in suitcase **and** a stroller **and** a baby seat.</sup>